# How to make packets flow from source node to destination node through multiple nodes?

Tags: ns2

For example if I have 5 nodes in a wireless network. I want the packets from node 1 to reach node 5 through the path 2 -> 3 -> 4-> 5. How do i do it using ns2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the sender node index and receiver node index, you can't give a path (route) like 2 -> 3 -> 4-> 5. the path selection will based on protocol you used in your simulation (like AODV or DSR) but you  can do the above thing by placing a nodes in sequence order.